# iphone - passing an object on an UIToolbarButton action

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

Is that possible to make a UIToolbarButton pass an object to its target by using some exoteric method (as it seems not to be possible using regular button use)?

I mean something like

```
UIBarButtonItem *Button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:buttonImage
  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething:) **withObject:usingThis**];
```

I know I can trigger a method that will launch the full method with the object, but for the sake of elegance I was trying to minimize the code... I suspect it is not possible, but as you guys out there are insanely good you may come with an transcendental answer... who knows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to extend the UIBarButtonItem class.

Here is an example creating RCBarButtonItem class. I've used initWithTitle for ease, I'm sure you could change it...

*The UIBarButtonItem Subclass*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem {
    id anObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id anObject;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action withObject:(id)obj;

@end

@implementation RCBarButtonItem

@synthesize anObject;

-(void)dealloc {
    [anObject release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action withObject:(id)obj {
    if (self = [super initWithTitle:title style:style target:target action:action]) {
        self.anObject = obj;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then this could then be implemented like so:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "RCBarButtonItem.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RCBarButtonItem *button = [[RCBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(doSomething:)
                                                          withObject:@"Bye"];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;

}

- (void)doSomething:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", [(RCBarButtonItem *)sender anObject]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in this situation is create an NSDictionary property called, say, `buttonArguments`:

```
self. buttonArguments = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: usingThis, Button, ... , nil];
```

Then in your `doSomething:` method, look up the object based on the `sender` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using categories:

> UIBarButtonItem+BarButtonItem.h

```
@interface UIBarButtonItem (BarButtonItem)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userInfo;
@end
```

> UIBarButtonItem+BarButtonItem.m

```
static void *kUserInfo = &kUserInfo;

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (BarButtonItem)

- (NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kUserInfo);
}

- (void)setUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kUserInfo, userInfo, 
        OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```